# The Fundamental Theorem of Logic according to Wang

Tags: logic

Wang's "Proving theorems by pattern recognition II", page 3 says:

[image]
[image]

What is the "fundamental theorem of logic"?

Comment: Completeness: (1.3.1) and (1.3.2) are one the negation of the other. Thus, (a) 1.3.1 is a theorem of predicate calculus iff (c) 1.3.2. is not satisfiable i.e. iff 1.3.1 is valid.

Comment: Title asks for fundamental *problem*, body, for fundamental *theorem*. Please edit for consistency, Rodrigo.

Comment: @GerryMyerson done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See PROCESS AND EXISTENCE IN MATHEMATICS (1961), reprinted into: [Computation, Logic, Philosophy: A Collection of Essays (Kluwer, 1990)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Computation_Logic_Philosophy/KvX1CAAAQBAJ), page 44:

> It seems reasonable to suppose that if a theory is consistent, it must have some interpretation. [...] The fundamental theorem of logic gives a sharper answer for theories formulated as formal systems within the framework of logic, i.e., the theory of quantifiers: any such theory, if consistent, has a relatively simple model in the theory of positive integers, simple in the sense that rather low level
> predicates in the arithmetic hierarchy would suffice.

And see page 116 for reference to [Herbrand's fundamental theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.01412).

---

*Note* In the book above we can find reprinted both "Proving theorems by pattern recognition I" and "Proving theorems by pattern recognition II".

Comment: Self-promotion: I included a short (3 pages), purely semantical explanation of Herbrand's theorem in Section 3 of a paper "Resource Consciousness in Classical Logic" [ in "Games,
    Logic, and Constructive Sets" (G. Mints and R. Muskens, eds.) CSLI
  Lecture Notes 161 (2003) 61--74], available in pre-publication form at http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/llc9.pdf .